# How to fix gradle issue Val cannot be reassigned after gradle upgrade

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have upgraded my android gradle to use latest 7.1.1

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-all.zip
```

after updated libraries to latest I get an error on `dynemicFeatures`

```
build.gradle.kts:224:5: Val cannot be reassigned
```

[image]

when I navigate to dynemaicFeatures i see this

```
package com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl

import com.android.build.api.dsl.ApplicationBuildFeatures
import com.android.build.api.dsl.ApplicationExtension
import com.android.build.api.variant.ApplicationVariant
import com.android.build.api.variant.ApplicationVariantBuilder
import com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidSourceSet
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.CompileOptions
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.coverage.JacocoOptions

/** See [InternalCommonExtension] */
interface InternalApplicationExtension :
    ApplicationExtension<
        AndroidSourceSet,
        BuildType,
        DefaultConfig,
        ProductFlavor,
        SigningConfig>,
        InternalCommonExtension<
                ApplicationBuildFeatures,
                BuildType,
                DefaultConfig,
                ProductFlavor,
                ApplicationVariantBuilder,
                ApplicationVariant> {
    override var dynamicFeatures: MutableSet<String>
    override var assetPacks: MutableSet<String>
}
```

Could you please provide any pointers on how to fix this please

thanks in advance
R

Comment: where did u declare dynamicFeatures ??

Comment: only reference I can see for dynamicFeaturs is in build.gradle.kts - `dynamicFeatures = mutableSetOf()`, 
when I click on dynamicFeatures it navigated me to `InternalApplicationExtension ` interface

Comment: @BRDroid Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue.
As solution i just used addAll() instead of reassign property:

```
  dynamicFeatures.addAll(
            setOf(
                ":feature1",
                ":feature2",
                ":feature3",
                ":feature4"
            )
        )
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding, could you let me know what is feature1, feature2, feature3, please